# Path figure over the agent figure on 2d visualization ANYLOGIC

Tags: simulation, anylogic

I've just built a model of an airport. I've created an agent called 'airplane' and, when it moves along the path, in the 2D visualization I see the path figure over the airplane figure (instead the 3D is okay). Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Z-order in the 2D visualization is not in connection with the Z-values set for 3D animation. If the airplane agent population lives in the main agent, then you can see the agent presentation in the origin. I assume the paths are simply created in Main. Drag the airplane presentation on a path and use 'Bring forward' or 'Bring to front' actions until you see the airplane above the path, then move it back to the origin.

I'm not sure how/if this could be solved without having a custom population in Main.